# Change Existing Liferay 7 classes

Tags: liferay, osgi, liferay-7

I need to make some changes to the liferay 7 private messaging portlet and I wanted to ask:

Is there a way to override liferay portal classes using a module ? In my case I want to change the class PrivateMessagingUtil.

Best regards,

Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **customize Liferay 7 services** creating a **servicewrapper project** type.
You can create it using the command line:

```
blade create -t service-wrapper -p com.liferay.docs.serviceoverride -c UserLocalServiceOverride -s com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.UserLocalServiceWrapper service-override
```

I needed the password change confirmation email not sent to the user, so I override updatePassword method from class UserLocalServiceWrapper and pass silentUpdate as true.

```
@Component(
immediate = true,
property = {
},
service = ServiceWrapper.class)

public class UserLocalServiceOverride extends UserLocalServiceWrapper {

public UserLocalServiceOverride() {
    super(null);
}

@Override
public com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.User updatePassword(long userId,
    java.lang.String password1, java.lang.String password2,
    boolean passwordReset)
    throws com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.PortalException {

    return updatePassword(userId,
            password1, password2,
            passwordReset, true);
}

@Override
public com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.User updatePassword(long userId,
    java.lang.String password1, java.lang.String password2,
    boolean passwordReset, boolean silentUpdate)
    throws com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.PortalException {

    return super.updatePassword(userId, password1, password2,
        passwordReset, silentUpdate);
}
}
```

Look at this link from Liferay documentation:

https://dev.liferay.com/es/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/customizing-liferay-services-service-wrappers

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at code: *If* there is an extension point: Use it. As you name the class that you'd like to change, I assume that there is none, so the extension points are probably in other classes that call this method. Not every single class has an extension point. If everything else fails, you'll have to bite the bullet and maintain a branch version - at least it's (probably, I haven't looked at the code) a plugin, so the size and impact would be relatively limited.

If there is a good story behind the changes you'd like to make, please [file a ticket](https://issues.liferay.com), even better with a proposed implementation. Discuss with the component owner.

...and answering Daniele's comment question separately here: I didn't look at the code - that's the problem with this kind of question: In a different mood I'd have rejected the question "I want to change some code in class Xxx" with a counter-question in a comment: "*What* are you *actually* trying to *achieve*?" Quite often there are better solutions, but when a technical question like this is asked, any answer might be suboptimal. Because Breiti has chosen the solution that he's intending to use for solving his problem, I stand by my words - feel free to add a better answer, assuming his actual intent.

Comment: Hi Olaf, why don't you suggest to implement a new version of social-private-messaging-service osgi module ?

Comment: Because I didn't look at the code. That's your opportunity for a, better answer :)

Comment: Hi, is there any documentation or any book on how to create a new version of service osgi modules ?

Comment: https://dev.liferay.com and https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples are good starting points